# Can a repeated property be used as a regular property in NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

In Google App Engine's NDB, say that I need an entity to:

- contain sometimes a string
- contain sometimes a list of strings
- the field is never required
- I never need both at the same time

Given the queries on a repeated property with a single element work the same as with a non-repeated property, will there be a performance difference or any disadvantages in having a single repeated field even when I will sometimes use it as a regular StringProperty? (leaving aside the better readability of having different fields for repeated and non-repeated)

Basically:

```
class model1(ndb.Model):
    str1 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

vs

```
class model2(ndb.Model):
    str1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    str2 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, but the field will be a list.
If you don't store anything it will be an empty list. If you add a string it will be a list with one value.

Remember that as this field will be a list, then to add values just call "field.append(yourstring)

Comment: Thanks, will there be a cost/performance penalty when querying from a one-element list compared to a single field?

Comment: None as they have an index. Even if you have a 1000 elements the cost will be the same